# How to Binding Data in RecyclerView with Tab View Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, android-recyclerview

I have 3 Tab in my Application. Let say the first is A, B, and C. My MainActivity declare and set a Tab Listener and i have 3 Activity again for my every Tab. My problem is, in Tab A i load data with Volley. In Tab B i load different data too. But sometime my RecyclerView  , the data was weird (data in Tab B shown in Tab A or Tab B success load the data but Tab A not shown anything). I load the data in every Activity Tab like my code below. Do i do a mistake? Or should i load all data in MainActivity? any answer will help for me. Thanks Before

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popular_tab, container, false);


    searchViewPopular = (SearchView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.searchView_Popular);

    popularRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_Popular);
    popularRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    popularaLinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    popularGenericAdapter = new GenericAdapter(popularRecyclerView);

    popularRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(popularaLinearLayoutManager);
    popularRecyclerView.setAdapter(popularGenericAdapter);

    popularData = new JSONArray();
    filteredPopularData = new JSONArray();

    filteredPopularData = ((GlobalVariable)this.getActivity().getApplication()).getPopularData();

    loadData();

    listener = new GenericAdapter.OnRecyclerViewListener() {
        @Override
        public void OnRecyclerViewItemClicked(RecyclerView recyclerView, int position) {

        }

        @Override
        public void OnRecyclerViewItemBind(RecyclerView recyclerView, GenericAdapter.GenericHolder view, int position) {
            try {
                currPopularData = filteredPopularData.getJSONObject(position);

                view.textViewTitle.setText(currPopularData.getString("title"));
                view.textViewDesc.setText("Popularity       : " + currPopularData.getString("popularity"));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public int OnRecyclerViewItemCount(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
            return filteredPopularData.length();
        }
    };

    popularGenericAdapter.setOnRecyclerViewListener(listener);
    searchViewPopular.setOnQueryTextListener(searchListener);

    return rootView;
}

//  @Override
//  public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //   super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    //  loadData();
//  }

SearchView.OnQueryTextListener searchListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String searchText) {
        try {
            filteredPopularData = ProgramMethod.filterArray(popularData, "title", searchText, false);
            popularGenericAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }
};

    public void loadData() {
    final RequestQueue requestQueue;
    Network network = new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack());
    requestQueue = new RequestQueue(new NoCache(), network);
    requestQueue.start();

    final String urlAPIGenre = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=8517f7eb51ca49a4558f33f8c832c1db";
    final String TAG = "";

    final JsonObjectRequest jsonGenre = new JsonObjectRequest
            (Request.Method.GET, urlAPIGenre, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        popularData = response.getJSONArray("results");
                        filteredPopularData = popularData;

                        ((GlobalVariable)getActivity().getApplication()).setPopularData(filteredPopularData);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    System.out.println("filteredPopularData = " + response);
                    popularGenericAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                }
            });
    requestQueue.add(jsonGenre);
}
```

EDIT :

this is below my Tab

[image]

[image]

[image]

In first tab, it should be show Textview with text `Popularity` but in the first time App open its always show `Top Rated` content

Comment: If you use viewPager try adding `viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(5);` in MainActivity. May be this could hep. Which could prevent data to be loaded again while swiping back and forth between tabs.

Comment: @AshwinMothilal its not work

Comment: Some screenshots could help

Comment: @AshwinMothilal added, see my edit